# How to send webcam stream to wowzaurl using webrtc

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have to send stream to wowza url using webrtc. I am able to display webcam stream to browser but for going further I have no Idea about this.

```
var videoContainer = document.getElementById('video'),
      vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
      var code;

      navigator.getMedia({
        video:true,
        audio:false
      }, function (stream){
           code = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
        console.log(code);
          videoContainer.src = code;
        videoContainer.play();
      }, function (error){
          console.log(error);
      })


    myAppService.createLiveVideo(user).then(function(response){
      var streamUrl = code.substring(code.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
      var url = 'rtmp://' + response.data.data.liveVideoInfo.unicastBasePath + '/'+ streamUrl;

    }, function(){

    })
```

Comment: You should consult the wowza documentation or perhaps support. You can't just send video to a url using WebRTC.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Update:

<strike>You can't.</strike> As @Aleks pointed out in the comments there is now a [preview of Wowza WebRTC](https://www.wowza.com/products/capabilities/webrtc-streaming-software) support available.

Original:

You can't.

Wowza does not currently have any support for WebRTC ([wowza forums post](https://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?34605-WebRTC-Support-in-Wowza)). Even if you were to wire up your own RTSP or RTMP signalling in the browser the Wowza RTP stack will still not be able to carry out the required ICE and STUN checks.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you point me out some tutorial or link where can I read about webrtc. I am just curious about the javascript part which send webcam stream to server.

Comment: webrtc.org. WebRTC is best suited to peer-to-peer communications (browser to browser really). I you want to stream a webcam to a server there are better ways.

Comment: The answer is now "Yes you can!" The actual forum post now says that it is currently in preview state, and there is a possibility it will be commercially available in some near future.